# xrandr changes X's orientation too slowly

Tags: linux, xorg, orientation, xrandr

I'm changing X's orientation with following command

xrandr -o left
xrandr -o normal
...

When orientation is changing screen becomes black for a moment then it switches orientation.
So how to get rid of this black screen effect ? Maybe some other options should be added to xrandr ?

Regards,
Levon

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the reason of the problem and posted corresponding bug.
For details see in my blog
http://levonp.blogspot.com/2010/11/xserver-black-screen-delay-when.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, because of the way X and randr works, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the transition from normal mode to inverted is being done very smoothly. But transition from inverted to normal mode is being done with black screen effect. 
Please provide more info on kernel mode settings concerning this